# Библиотека Jetpack Compose

Tags: библиотеки, поиск-библиотек, android-jetpack-compose

Я помню, существовала библиотека для Jetpack Compose, которая позволяла использовать `.vw` и `.vh` как единицы измерения, по типу `.dp`. Но когда я пытался ее найти я буквально застрял в поисках, как будто этой библиотеки никогда и не было. При том, я помню, что расстроился, когда пытался добавить ее в проект compose-desktop. К сожалению, винда слетела и проекта тоже не осталось. Кто-нибудь знает про эту библиотеку? Помогите найти, пожалуйста!

Помню что там у проекта на превью что-то по типу магазина было реализовано и сумка синяя как товар

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы быстрее сами бы написали. `BoxWithConstraints` + `CompositionLocal` и пара методов расширений по типу `.dp`

Впрочем, можно и еще проще (если я правильно понимаю что такое vh и vw)

```
inline val Int.vh: Dp
    @Composable get() {
        val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.run { screenHeightDp.dp  }
        return this * (screenHeight / 100)
    }

inline val Int.vw: Dp
    @Composable get() {
        val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.run { screenWidthDp.dp  }
        return this * (screenWidth / 100)
    }
```

Comment: Конечно здорово, что вы смогли написать реализацию, но хочется проверить не попал ли я в параллельную вселенную (или приобрел эффект Манделы своеобразный). Однако, копипастить этот код в каждый свой проект не очень классная идея :)

Comment: В нашей вселенной PHP давно умер, а 1С считается одним из лучших языков и даже англичане теперь учат русский язык, чтобы писать на 1С. Теперь думай сам, куда ты попал.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант на сайте с документацией по разработке Android приложений имеется описание по работе с компрессом https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup, а также ссылки на простые проекты https://github.com/android/compose-samples

Comment: Я ищу конкретно библиотеку, которая позволяет использовать единицы vh и vw

Comment: @AdisAlagic извняюсь, не понял сразу. Подумал, что нужно как-то запуститься с jetpack-compose